# Vlookup in text array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't figure out how to use excel in my situation.
I have text in column (B) with string values with Code inside them which I need to extract (e.g. cells in column B can contain "words..irrelevant info...CODE..again words... and so on).
In column "E" I need to find if values of array (D) is inside B cell. If it is then I need to take C column with Price.

I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

[image]

Edit: The user "yass" answered my question, his formula works greate, but I have a problem to MATCH exact "CODE". For e.g. I have made new table, as you can see this formula doesn't determine that CODE "ABC1" and "ABC123WRONG" has different names, so the price for it is wrong(.

I attached screenshot below. Please, help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E5 write the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$7,MATCH("*"&D5&"*",$B$5:$B$7,0)),"")
```

and drag it down
$C$5:$C$7 the price column
$B$5:$B$7 where you have text with the code
D5 the code that you want to find in column B and return the corresponding price

**Update**
To correspond to the new screenshot with similar values you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$9,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&D5&",*",$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH("*"&D5&",*",$B$5:$B$9,0),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&D5,$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH("*"&D5,$B$5:$B$9,0),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D5&"*",$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH(D5&"*",$B$5:$B$9,0),"")))),"Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added additional description of my issue in post.

Comment: If "," is always after the code you can add it in the formula

Comment: Hello, yass! Could you help one more time please? Is it possible to modify the formula like this: It searches  "Space symbol" or "comma" before D5 and     "Space symbol" or "comma"  after D5. I'm writing it like this, but seems syntaxic is wrong.                       

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$7,MATCH(Or(" ",",") &D5&Or(" ",","),$B$5:$B$7,0)),"")`

Comment: Try this =IFERROR(INDEX($C$5:$C$9,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&D5&",*",$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH("*"&D5&",*",$B$5:$B$9,0),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&D5,$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH("*"&D5,$B$5:$B$9,0),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D5&"*",$B$5:$B$9,0)),MATCH(D5&"*",$B$5:$B$9,0),"")))),"Not Found")